# Building User Interface in Android - Views vs. XML

Tags: android, xml, view, android-activity, android-layout

I am very new to Android development and, while I get the general premise (and have even built a small application), I have been looking at other developer's source code to get an idea of how to better approach my development for larger projects.

One developer's code is read is basically using both XML layouts and Views for the various parts to the UI (similar to what is being asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364433/using-both-xml-and-coded-views-in-android)). I understand what he is doing, but it seems overly complicated to me. The XML layouts provide functionality already to create responses to actions. (For example, "onClick" is provided for most components in the XML.) Layouts can be generated very easily with the XML.

So, my question is - can I get away with building my entire application using just Activities and XML layouts? Can I choose not to use any Views? (Of course, this is assuming a relatively simple app - think task list or something similar.) Or, am I trying to simplify too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general strategy I use is to push as much as possible into XML. It's a very different way of thinking from some other UI development systems, but it's very cool once you get past the learning curve.

I don't know what you mean by choosing "not to use any Views". Every UI component is a View of some sort. If you mean not using any custom View subclasses, then yes, it is definitely possible. The only reason to create your own custom View classes (and then use them in XML!) is when the stock widgets and views don't do what you want. Since they are quite flexible, this tends to be fairly uncommon (until you start getting into fancy behavior or need custom graphics behavior).

Comment: Just adding- all of my layouts are defined using XML. Whilst coding your layout in Java may have it advantages, with XML you get a WYSIWYG editor and a much easier time defining your layout. The only niggle is that if you want to do anything with your `Views` once they're defined in XML is that you have to fetch them using `findViewById`. But definitely go for XML over Java.

Comment: Yes, I did mean custom View subclasses. Thank you for the clarification. So, as long as I don't need some custom dynamic behavior, I should be good creating my views directly from XML. If that's the case, excellent! It's what I suspected from reading, but I wasn't *quite* sure.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for Creating UI for Android Application. They are

1. Using XML - You can use xml for designing UI targeted for supporting Multiple device. Also XML helps you to create Static components.
2. Java Code -Generally  it's not a good practice to creating UI in java. Its suitable,  if you creating a samll application. Its also useful when you want to develop application with dynamic components. If you want to create Dynamic Components in UI, Java code helps you to achieve this.

The Good Approach is to create UI via XML, unless there's no dynamic component needed in the UI. if you need dynamic UI creation then you go custom UI creation i,e., Using Java Code.

Since you are New to Android, i would like you to refer [android developer site](http://developer.android.com)

Comment: Even if you need dynamic views, you can use a mix of pre-build XML that have a lot of cases of what you need all with visibility gone, and just change their visibility as you need them. When you don't know nothing about what the UI will be like.. than ok, Java is the only approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand, XML layouts are just a shortcut for creating views. You end up with the same results at runtime either way. Mix, match, use one or the other, it's up to you.